# Css arrow animation

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I'm trying to animate an arrow with css. On hover, I want to expand it to the left instead of to the right (should get longer). Any idea how I can achieve that?

```css
svg path {
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

svg {
  cursor: pointer;
}

svg:hover path {
  d: path("M46.7497 1.05713L60 14.5066M60 14.5066L46.7497 27.9561M60 14.5066H1");
  d: "M46.7497 1.05713L60 14.5066M60 14.5066L46.7497 27.9561M60 14.5066H1";
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-container">
  <svg width="100" height="29" viewBox="0 0 50 29" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path class="arrow-line" d="M35.7497 1L49 14.4495M49 14.4495L35.7497 27.8989M49 14.4495H1.5" stroke="#18181B" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dasharray="2 5"/>
        </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Copy that **d="..."** path and paste it into the editor: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor

Comment: Or rotate the current SVG 180degrees... but that is...

Answer (score 0):

You can animate the `d` attribute -- an alternative is to use transform/traslate. Use the [SvgPathEditor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) to flip the path by setting scale x to -1.

```css
svg path {
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

svg {
  cursor: pointer;
}

svg path {
  transform: translate(15px, 2px);
}

svg:hover path {
  transform: translate(1px, 2px);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-container">
  <svg height="29" viewBox="0 0 60 28" fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path class="arrow-line" d="m 13 0 l -13 13 m 0 0 l 13 13 m -13 -13 h 58"
      stroke="#18181B" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round"
      stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dasharray="2 5"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```